# HttpResponseCache not caching urls without Content-Length header

Tags: java, android, node.js, caching, cache-control

Using the stock Android examples for HttpURLConnection and HttpResponseCache, I have created a [bare bones app](https://github.com/chris-gunawardena/tmp-android-http-cache-test/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ibm/chris/httpcachetest/MainActivity.java) that calls two urls, twice. [First one without Content-Length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCQ8q.png) and the [second one with Content-Length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6iCG.png).

I can see in charles that the endpoint without Content-Length does not get cached. I removed Content-Length from the caching url and confirmed that this prevents it from caching as well.

Unfortunately there is no way to have gzipping and Content-Length in restify according to the [Gzip plugin docs](http://restify.com/docs/plugins-api/).

Is there a way to force HttpResponseCache to cache a url even when Content-Length is missing? Also what is the logic behind not caching urls without Content-Length? (iOS caches properly without Content-Length)

*Using Volly or Restify is a last resort due to large existing codebase.

Comment: "Is there a way to force HttpResponseCache to cache a url even when Content-Length is missing?" -- I doubt it, short of a custom ROM. "Also what is the logic behind not caching urls without Content-Length?" -- questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are unsuitable for Stack Overflow, as usually only Developer X can answer, and Developer X is unlikely to see your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare I thought maybe Content-Length is required by some http spec or something like that.

Comment: I don't think that there is a spec that defines the behavior of client-side caches.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks makes sense, only asked becasue I came across https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3 but wasn't sure if it was related.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up moving to retrofit which had no issues caching without Content-Length header.